# Is there a more efficient way to find the powers of a number?

Tags: c++, performance

So I have a program that will call the 'pow' function written below multiple times. My question is, is there any way to optimize my 'pow' function any further? The way I see it, whenever I call the function and the answer to the question that is being asked is not known (Say the question is, "what is 26^5?"), the program calculates the answer, and there stores it in an array to be used later. Memory is not a concern here, just execution time. Also, my 'pow' function only needs to calculate powers of 26, as I use it to calculate permutations of the English alphabet.

```
 unsigned long long int pow(int x)
{
    unsigned long long int rez=1;
    int ct1=1; //this variable is used to walk through the array from right to left (see the while loop)
    val[0]=1; //I store in the array 'val' the values of (26^index) e.g val[0]=26^0=1, 'val' is of the type unsigned long long 
    val[1]=26;
    if(val[x]==0){ // if the value of 26^x is not already calculated, i find the first power smaller than x that is calculated
    while(val[x-ct1]==0 and (x-ct1)>1)
        ct1++;
    rez=(val[x-ct1])%mod; // my result (here called 'rez') is equal to said already calculated power
    for(int i=x-ct1+1; i<=x; i++){ //for loop that calculates 26^x
        rez*=26;
        rez=rez%mod;
        val[i]=rez; // i store each power newly calculated in 'val'
        }

    return rez; //i return the result, via the 'rez' variable
    }
    else{//else, if the value was already known, I simply return val[x]
        return val[x];
    }

} //side note: every variable that I expect to take big values is reduced to %mod, where mod=1000000007
```

Comment: Working code is better reviewed over at [codereview.se].

Comment: Table might be constructed at compile time, then you just access your "cache" result.

Comment: The definitions of `val` and `mod` are missing. (Code Review also wants complete code)

Answer (score 2):

A more efficient, elegant and universal solution is the **"quick-pow-algorithm"**.Here is my implementation to calculate the result of a^b %MOD based on C language.

```
const int MOD = 1e9 + 7;
long long quick_pow(long long a, long long b)
{
    long long res = 1;
    while (b) {
        if (b & 1) res = res * a % MOD;
        a = a * a;
        b >>= 1;
    }
    return res;
}
```

the time is **O(log b)** level.
And pay attention to the range of number.product is often overflow in this algorithm.So if overflow happens, you can add another algorithm that is called **"the slow multiple"** to this method.
That is the implentation of the slow multiple.Its core thought is totally same as the quick pow.

```
int slow_mul(int a, int b, int p){
    int res = 0;
    while (b) {
        if (b&1) res=(res + a) % p;
        a = (a + a) % p;
        b >>= 1;
    }
    return res;
}
```

the slow-mul can calculate the a * b % p **in O(log b) time**, which is slower than O(1) which the small number product need.That is the reason it gets its name "slow multiple".

By the way, we should think more about this question.For example,how to deal with it if the varible b is negative or zero? I mean,the boundary situation and special situation must be considered when we think about our algorithm design to solving different problems.Not for this question,but for every question.

Comment: This is not a bad idea per se, but it doesn't really address the question. The cache in the question can give answers in O(1).